# error: Non-nullable instance field 'textResult' must be initialized

Tags: flutter, dart

error: Non-nullable instance field 'textResult' must be initialized. (not_initialized_non_nullable_instance_field at [aplikasi_scan_plat_nomor] lib\screen\home.dart:18)

class _HomeState extends State {
String textResult;

Answer (score 0):

With the sound null safety, our definitions should care about null cases.
So you can use `String textResult = "";` or `String? textResult;` for your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can add late keyword before the variable.